# ANT - Run a single target but without dependencies

Tags: java, ant, build

I know how to run a single target in ANT, but it also checks the "depends" attribute and runs those before the target. Is there a way to prevent this or a way to structure my ANT file so that I can do this more easily?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a "withoutdeps" version of the target. If you had

```
<target name="A" depends="B">
   ...
</target>
```

Change to

```
<target name="A" depends="B,AwithoutDeps"/>

<target name="AwithoutDeps">
    ...
</target>
```

Now you can call A as normal (which will fire off B then AwithoutDeps) or just call AwithoutDeps explicitly and no deps fired. [Note that "depends" calls the dependencies in order]

Of course, choose some better names than these ;)

Comment: Very similar to my solution - I think the difference is just a question of style.  This exploits the dependency functionality of ant, my solution exploits the "encapsulation" functionality.

Comment: Thanks! This seems cleaner than copying and pasting.

Comment: @Jared - I thought about of antcall as well, but it's more expensive AFAIK, as it sets up a copy of the properties and such. Not that it's a huge deal though...

Comment: @Scott - if only my build were sufficiently quick/efficient that I was worried about the cost of a copy of the properties :P...oh to have that problem :P

Answer (score 2):

I think your only simple choice here would be to just make a copy of the target in question and make it not have dependencies.

Comment: I am just removing the depends attributes now (which is almost the same thing), but I am wondering for a possibly cleaner solution.

Comment: Would be nice to have this an an option to the ant command line.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use the `if` or `unless` attribute on the dependency target(s).  For example:

```
<target name="dependency1" unless="dependency1.disabled">
  <echo>Hello from dependency 1!</echo>
</target>

<target name="dependency2" unless="dependency2.disabled">
  <echo>Hello from dependency 2!</echo>
</target>

<target name="main-target" depends="dependency1, dependency2">
  <echo>Hello from the main target!</echo>
</target>
```

Now you can run Ant with `-Ddependency1.disabled=true` and/or `-Ddependency2.disabled=true` to leave out the dependencies you don't want, but the default will still be to include them.

And of course, you could simply have a "global" `dependencies.disabled` property if that's easier for you.

If you want to do the *converse* of this behavior (where the dependencies are excluded by default), just use the `if` instead of `unless` (and have property names like "dependency1.enabled" instead of "disabled").

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
<target name="doSomethingNoDeps">
   ...
</target>

<target name="doSomething" depends="doSomeOther">
  <antcall target="doSomethingNoDeps"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Ant 1.7.1, it includes following class: `org.apache.tools.ant.helper.IgnoreDependenciesExecutor`
which basically does what it's name implies.

The use of this class can be configured by setting the system variable `ant.executor.class` on the command-line, so basically:
`-Dant.executor.class={{the above classname}}`

According to the [docs](https://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#sysprops), this is possible since Ant 1.6.3

Answer (score -1):

I made macro with piece of code, what I want.
Then made 2 targets, 1 calls macro with "arg1", 2nd with "arg2".
You can also make macro without accepting parameters.

```
<macrodef name="macro-jar">
    <attribute name="dir" />
    <sequential>
        <jar destfile="${jar.name}">
            <fileset dir="@{dir}" .../>
            ...
            ...
        </jar>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Calling it from 2 places in code:
1st:

```
<macro-jar dir="${dir.build}" />
```

2nd:

```
<macro-jar dir="${dir.temp}" />
```

Comment: an answer should show how to solve the problem. show what you did.